# Why asymmetric fission product is so enhanced?

Tags: nuclear-physics

The thermal fission yield of usual Pu, U mix

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission#/media/File:ThermalFissionYield.svg

is tuned in a way that practically ignores symmetric yield. But if we calculate the final products for split, they are symmetric channels with energy even better that the extreme asymmetric ones. For example for U233, either spontaneus or after eating a neutron, we could contemplate a lot of states with near 200 Mev of energy gain.

```
S     T1      T2      E (KeV)    Asym
U233 107 Ru  126 Cd  193037.556 8
U233 116 Pd  117 Pd  193176.788 0
U233 99 Nb  134 Sb  193272.59 15
U234 105 Tc  129 In  193277.667 10
U233 108 Tc  125 In  193317.839 7
U233 105 Tc  128 In  193359.151 9
U234 116 Pd  118 Pd  193367.56 0
U233 104 Nb  129 Sb  193374.773 10
U233 107 Tc  126 In  193441.085 8
U234 99 Zr  135 Te  193499.113 15
U233 108 Mo  125 Sn  193579.022 7
U233 106 Tc  127 In  193593.936 9
U233 112 Ru  121 Cd  193622.79 3
U233 102 Zr  131 Te  193725.026 12
U234 107 Tc  127 In  193793.028 8
U234 98 Zr  136 Te  193865.146 16
U233 108 Ru  125 Cd  193927.666 7
U233 100 Mo  133 Sn  193983.942 14
U234 108 Ru  126 Cd  194062.948 7
U234 102 Nb  132 Sb  194093.0 12
U234 107 Mo  127 Sn  194175.966 8
U233 103 Nb  130 Sb  194231.619 11
U234 101 Zr  133 Te  194249.638 13
U233 97 Zr  136 Te  194294.475 16
U233 111 Ru  122 Cd  194315.811 4
U233 109 Ru  124 Cd  194358.276 6
U234 112 Ru  122 Cd  194387.912 4
U233 110 Ru  123 Cd  194405.01 5
U234 110 Ru  124 Cd  194919.074 5
U234 108 Mo  126 Sn  194924.462 7
U234 102 Zr  132 Te  194928.775 12
U234 103 Nb  131 Sb  195153.833 11
U233 102 Nb  131 Sb  195212.759 12
U233 101 Zr  132 Te  195279.189 13
U233 101 Nb  132 Sb  195443.817 13
U233 107 Mo  126 Sn  195493.448 8
U233 100 Nb  133 Sb  195646.095 14
U233 98 Zr  135 Te  195940.627 15
U234 101 Nb  133 Sb  195957.325 13
U234 105 Mo  129 Sn  196097.165 10
U233 100 Zr  133 Te  196234.285 14
U234 103 Mo  131 Sn  196385.739 11
U233 106 Mo  127 Sn  196532.303 9
U233 101 Mo  132 Sn  196980.569 13
U234 100 Zr  134 Te  197064.795 14
U233 99 Zr  134 Te  197080.676 15
U233 105 Mo  128 Sn  197625.51 9
U234 106 Mo  128 Sn  197649.668 9
U233 102 Mo  131 Sn  197762.844 12
U233 104 Mo  129 Sn  197883.269 10
U233 103 Mo  130 Sn  198019.898 11
U234 102 Mo  132 Sn  198261.202 12
U234 104 Mo  130 Sn  198635.602 11
```

So that some extra enhancement mechanism is needed to "flatify" the A=110-125 area. I read that current liquid-drop simulations trace some "potential valley" during the start of the fission process and that these valleys mark the final destination. It could be, but is it so huge the effect to completely nullify the symmetric splits? Note that this other question [What decides fission products?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102711/what-decides-fission-products) tells that the excited fission is symmetric.

Comment: Table calculated from data https://www-nds.iaea.org/amdc/ame2012/mass.mas12